# ID of users Google home folder (My Drive)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-directory-api

As an admin on our Google domain I want to be able to drop a folder shortcut into our student's Google home folder (their 'My Drive').

How can I get the ID of their home folder (their 'My Drive') - every folder must have an ID, right?

(To clarify, I need to get a unique ID for each folder so I can access it programatically - the folder is also known as 'root' but this doesn't help.  Every Google folder has a unique ID and I can't believe these folders are any different).

I can't see anything in the Drive or Directory APIs.

Google support says

> 'We use the popular programming Q&A website Stack Overflow to field
> technical questions'

so I'm hoping someone from Google will help!

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to access the student's home folder? suppose you don't have access to that.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get the ID of their home folder (their 'My Drive') - every folder must have an ID, right?

Every user on Google drive has a root folder.  The id of that folder is "root" you can just place your shortcut there.

If you really want the "Real" file id for the root folder then

Do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%22root%22%7D&apix=true) and pass it root as the file id

```
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/root?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

response

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0AJpJkOVaKccEUk9PVA",
 "name": "My Drive",
 "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
}
```

Comment: Yep, I'd read that the folder is called 'root' but that doesn't allow you to access it programatically - a folder ID such as 123456789ABCDEF is unique and can be easily referenced.  The 'My Drive' folders must also have unique IDs as per the Google Drive system (as well as being known as 'root')?

Comment: Check edit.   just do a file.get on root it will give you its id

Comment: Many thanks, that's looking promising - but I'd have to 'impersonate' every student to get their particular root folder?

Comment: I could not find this anywhere in the Drive API documentation. Thanks for this!